# Как перезапустить форму Windows form?

Tags: c#, winapi

Всем привет.Вопрос следующий:
у меня есть форма и мне надо ,чтоб пользователь по нажатию на кнопку "Reset" обнулял форму(возвращал ее в исходное состояние,как при запуске).Еще что очень важно,чтоб она оставалась в том же месте после рестарта где и была.
Я писал так:

Application.Restart();

В принципе сойдет,но получается так что класс который находится в файле Program в котором находятся данные тоже затирается со всеми полями.Как сделать чтоб форма просто принимала свой первоначальный вид и оставалась на тех же координатах без потери данных в программе?

Comment: Форма - это класс с полями. Выставляйте её полям нужные вам значения и радуйтесь. Или просто эту форму закрывайте и отрывайте новую в том же самом месте.

Comment: а как запустить в том же месте?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такое решение(это program.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Form form = new Form1();
            form.DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry;

            while (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                form.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                form = new Form1();
                Application.Run(form);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А внутри кнопки рестарт:

```
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Retry;
        this.Close();
```

**Но это кривое решение :)**

**(собственно, как и перезапуск апликухи)**

---

**Я советую просто запомнить расположение всего что нужно на запуске формы, а потом на "рестарт" просто откатить это все назад, как советовал tym32167 в коментах к вопросу. Это умное и правильное решение :)**